# Can't get bind operator to work with discriminated union

Tags: f#, operators

I'm trying to use the "bind operator" (>>=) in my code.

If I use the operator I get a compile error, if I instead "inline" what the operator is supposed to do, it works.

```ml
type TestDI =
    private
    | A of string list
    | B of int list
with
    static member (>>=) (x: string list, f: TestDI -> 'a) =
        f <| A x

let func (t: TestDI) =
    match t with
    | A _ -> "a"
    | B _ -> "b"


// Expecting a type supporting the operator '>>=' but given a function type.
// You may be missing an argument to a function.
["a"] >>= func


// works
func <| A ["a"]
```

Obviously I'm missing something, can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use an operator, F# looks for it in order:

- as a `let`-defined operator;
- as a `static member`-defined operator on one of the two arguments' types. Here, the arguments you are passing to the operator are `string list` and `TestDI -> string`, so it won't look at the one you defined on `TestDI`.

So here the solution would be to `let`-define it instead:

```
type TestDI =
    private
    | A of string list
    | B of int list

let (>>=) (x: string list) (f: TestDI -> 'a) =
    f <| A x
```